# Couldn't open .bib.aux

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texmaker

I have a bibliography file called `mybib.bib`, and I wanted to create `.bbl` file so that I can copy its contents inside my `.tex` file, but when I ran from command line `bibtex mybib.bib` I got an error message saying

> "I couldn't open file name 'mybib.bib.aux'".

Any ideas what the problem might be and how to solve it? Also, since I'm using TeXmaker for writing LaTeX, is there any easier way to include `.bib` file inside my `.tex` file and automate all the necessary compilations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say you have a TeX code `mwe.tex`. There you use file `mybib.bib` for your bib entrys.

First you have to compile the TeX code with `pdflatex mwe.tex`.  That run creates an file `mwe.aux` containing the informations for building the bibliography and more. So you run second `bibtex mwe.aux` to get the resulting file `mwe.bbl` you can use as wished ...